# Нужна функция в java похожая на функцию *какой либо список*.index(*item в списке*) в python

Tags: java, python

Я начинаю изучать java после досконального изучения python.
В python есть функция, которая меня часто спасала, это .index()
Есть ли подобное в java?

Ну и вообще.
Есть ли смысл учить яву для геймдева?

Comment: если не нравится С++ для игр, то можно попровать C#  на UNITY.
Проблем с написанием кода поменьше, но зато есть все плюсы и минусы  UNITY.
Java разве что для браузерных игр...

Answer (score 2):

У интерфейса List есть метод indexOf(Object o), если нужен метод для поиска индекса объекта.

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

Джава хорошо подходит для разработки серверной части онлайновых игр.

Comment: Тоже ошибка компиляции, 
Как правильно написать?
arr.indexOf(*item который есть в arr*) ?

Comment: Это метод интерфейса List, а не массива. Можно обернуть массив в лист, используя статический метод класса Arrays. Тогда код будет выглядить так: java.util.Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(object)

Comment: Ох ява ява...
Спасибо, буду учитб

Answer (score 0):

В геймдеве индустриальным стандартом является С++, а если среди скриптовых языков, то Lua. В Java есть метод contains() в List.

Comment: Использую contains() - ошибка компиляции

Как его правильно использовать, так?
arr.contains(*какой либо item*)

Comment: Так, видимо я ошибся, но да ладно, сверху уже написали про indexOf(). Всё же совет про ЯП касается про клиентскую часть.